# Jar with dependencies spring boot gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I was trying to make a jar with dependencies because I was getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when starting the jar with `java -Dspring.config.location=myProperties -jar myJar`, after a lot of searching I found that I can achieve this using the following solution in the jar block:

```
from{
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
```

And all good with this except for the amount of time when building the jar (1 minute aprox), and according with this answer: [Gradle: Build 'fat jar' with Spring Boot Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578495/gradle-build-fat-jar-with-spring-boot-dependencies) I don't need to create an additional task, is enough with the `bootRepackage` but I'm getting the error that I mentioned above with `bootRepackage` and I don't understand why.

This is the content of my `build.gradle` and I'm using spring boot 1.5.15:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
buildscript {
    ext.springBootVersion = '1.5.15.RELEASE'
    ext.managementVersion = '1.0.6.RELEASE'
    ext.axis2Version = '1.7.9'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        //classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${managementVersion}"
        //classpath "com.intershop.gradle.wsdl:wsdl-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.15.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'

} 

configurations{
    implementation{
        exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp'


    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.6.1'

    implementation 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-jaxb:1.2.20'    

    implementation('org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:1.7.9'){
        exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
        //The exclude above don't work
    }

    implementation "org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:${axis2Version}"

    implementation "org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:${axis2Version}"
    implementation "org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:${axis2Version}"


}

wsdl {
    axis2 {
        genNameAxis2 {
           //someAxis2Tasks
        }
    }
}

wsdl2java {

    //someWsdlTasks   
}

wsdl2javaExt {
    cxfVersion = "3.2.1"
}

jar {
    manifest{
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'dummy.Application')
    }

    from{
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
    archiveBaseName = 'projectName'
    archiveVersion = '1.0.0'
}

bootRepackage{
    mainClass = 'dummy.Application'
    //classifier = 'boot' I'm getting an error with this argument
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()    
}


group = 'dummy.group'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read this ~ https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable

Comment: What’s the complete error that you are getting?

Comment: Remove the `jar` and `bootRepackage` task. Just run `./gradlew build` and you will get an executable jar.

Comment: After the @M.Deinum suggestion, I'm getting the same error:  
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: privateDependency`    
And this is the error @AndyWilkinson
@Phil yea I read that but is for spring 2.0.0, I'm using spring 1.5.15

Comment: If you get this exception while running the regular Spring Boot task you have a depndency that isn't in one of the configurations that is included in the jar. Please post the full stacktrace (and updated build file) in your question.

Answer (score 5):

I have this same problem after upgrading to Gradle 5 and using 'implementation' instead of 'compile' for my dependencies.

Gradle built a main jar with no sub-project jars or dependencies (no BOOT-INF/lib directory at all). Changing 'implementation' back to 'compile' in the parent project only fixed the problem (with no other changes).

So, apparently, the Spring Boot 1.5.9 Gradle plugin does not work with the new implementation configuration. Note that Spring Boot 2 and the new bootJar task work fine, this issue is only with the old bootRepackage and the new implementation configuration.

Comment: I have just replaced all "implementation" to "compile" (including "testCompile") and now I have a working standalone JAR. Thanks a lot!  (I'm using Gradle 6.7 with an old SpringBoot 1.5.9)