# Docker cannot find Resource on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dockerfile

I have a simple Gradle Spring Boot Java application, where I am trying to get some properties value from  "application.properties" and "application-dev.properties" using spring boot profiling. It is working fine and Spring Boot profile is loading when I try to run application on the local machine, but when when I try to run same application on the Docker, suddenly an error pops up which says that application is not able to find resources on the classpath.

Below is the project structure:

[image: Project structure of the application]

In the App.Config class I have the following code. As you can see I am trying to get property value from application.properties file.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

@Value("${host}")
private String host;
@Value("${map}")
private String map;

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public String getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(String map) {
    this.map = map;
}
}
```

application.properties contains following code:

```
map = Main-Map

spring.profiles.active=${profile}
```

application-dev.properties contains following code:

```
host = Development-host
```

As you can see I am setting profile value in application.properties from outside. That's what I am trying to inject through docker

Dockerfile contain following code:

```
FROM java:8

VOLUME /tmp

ENV tom=dev

ADD build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar

ADD build/resources/main/application.properties /app/application.properties

ADD build/resources/main/application-dev.properties /app/application-dev.properties

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
Dprofile=${tom}","-jar","app.jar", "- 
-spring.config.location=/app/application.properties, /app/application- 
dev.properties"]
```

I build Docker image using following command:

```
docker build -t demo:latest .
```

I run Docker using following command:

```
docker run -p 8083:8080 demo:latest
```

When I run `docker run` command, so comes below exception:

```
2019-12-12 07:09:50.405  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 
Starting DemoApplication on ed7cb11b8a34 with PID 1 (/app/app.jar started by root in /app)
2019-12-12 07:09:50.407  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The 
following profiles are active: dev
2019-12-12 07:09:50.603  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class 
[com.example.demo.DemoApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path 
resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2019-12-12 07:09:50.712 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : 
Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [   com.example.demo.DemoApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path 
resource [ application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Follow my github repository and use the docker file. it should fix your problem.

https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/products-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the docker. Have you tried building the jar file and running it by `java -jar`.

```
ADD build/resources/main/application.properties /app/application.properties

ADD build/resources/main/application-dev.properties /app/application-dev.properties
```

These are unnecessary too. When you create your artifact as fat/uber/Shadow jar, you will have your properties packaged in jar.

### How to build fat/uber/Shadow Jar (Spring boot Gradle)

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot ([Gradle: Build 'fat jar' with Spring Boot Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578495/gradle-build-fat-jar-with-spring-boot-dependencies))

**Alternative**

https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/ (https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you aren't building Fat Jar. You can utilize `spring-boot-maven-plugin` for that.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</plugin>
```

Then change your `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ENV tom=dev
COPY build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dprofile=${tom}","-jar","app.jar"]
```