# "no main manifest attribute" when building .jar (Gradle)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, manifest.mf

I've been trying many different things throughout various posts, but none of the solutions have helped me.

1. Creating an artifact through `Build` -> `Build artifacts...`, selecting directory for `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` as `main\resources` and running a generated `jar` file throws `no main manifest attribute`.
2. `<..>`, selecting directory for `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` as `main\java` and running a generated `jar` file returns `Could not find or load main class`.

My `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: <package>.MainApplication
```

Also, in my `build.gradle` I have:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': '<package>.MainApplication'
    }
}
```

I have tried creating a new project, but the problem persisted the same. I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

[Demo project example](https://www.mediafire.com/file/w8vhfvc24o91ayx/demo.zip/file) (FileMail), which produces my error.

[Demo project example](https://www.mediafire.com/file/w8vhfvc24o91ayx/demo.zip/file) (MediaFire)

**UPDATE 2:**

[Demo project 2 example](https://www.filemail.com/d/rkchgvygqrkbheb)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (sample project on GitHub would work).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, please see attached at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Please use something to share your code where I do not have to register

Comment: @UwePlonus, I've added link to `MediaFire`. I hope you can download now.

Comment: Your fat jar contains digital signatures, therefore it will not run: MANIFEST.MF
SIGNINGC.RSA
SIGNINGC.SF. These files were unpacked from one of your dependencies. They have to be removed from the fat jar.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, yes it did. Now I've created a new project without any dependencies and built a `jar` file again. It did not contain neither `SIGNINGC.RSA` nor `SIGNINGC.SF` but the error persisted the same.

Comment: Share your new project then.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, please see attached below update 2. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear how the jar in this project was built. There is no artifact for this jar configuration and Gradle builds a different jar without dependencies. The problem with the jar you have in `out\artifacts` is that it has Manifest file included from some different library and this manifest doesn't specify the main class. If you build it with IntelliJ IDEA artifacts feature, reorder the manifest in the included files so that the correct one is used, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116209#comment=27-656589 for more details.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I've disabled alphabetical order but the problem persisted. Then I changed resources folder to `src` directory and now it throws `No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories.`. But running `./gradlew build` works.

Comment: Yeah, packaging Spring apps in the fat jar can be a pain, use Gradle for that.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579556/104891 helps.