# NoClassDefFoundError in Java 17 while running generated jar on terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, java-17

I am trying to run my jar generated using ./gradlew clean build but I always get this error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
I am using java -jar command

```
   plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation('jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3')
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.test.TestApplication'
    }
}
```

The above is my build.gradle file.I have created my project using spring initializr.I have tested the same project using java 11 and it worked fie why is this causing issue with java 17 can anyone tell me what is the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578495/gradle-build-fat-jar-with-spring-boot-dependencies

Comment: This shouldn't work for any version of Java, and it also doesn't follow the template from the Spring Initializr project. My suggestion is to download the template _again_, making sure you select Gradle and Java 17, and go from there. You will find that there are no `jar` or `bootJar` references, which is what is causing the problem.